# Question mark for type parameters in typescript (const t: typeof T<?>)

Tags: typescript

I came across a weird Typescript error while reworking module registration code in my app.

```
abstract class Component<P, S> {
    state?: Readonly<S>;
    props?: P;
}

interface IModuleProperties {
    name: string;
}

interface IModuleState {
    index: number;
}

export class ModuleBase<P extends IModuleProperties, S extends IModuleState> extends Component<P, S> {
}

export class Module1 extends ModuleBase<IModuleProperties, IModuleState> {
}

const t: typeof ModuleBase = Module1;
const t2: typeof ModuleBase<?,?> = Module1;
```

[Here's the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQQwRgzgLgTiDGVjwDYghYBhA9gWwAccA7AU2KgB4AFAGmAGUA%20YAbwCgBIaEKUgfgBcwAEqkQAExIoAnpWYBuLgRg4CEIcGpKAvu3YBLCqRgAzBKWABJALI4JAVxSlqqgiagHSmDsD-BiEDxSYWgYIwBzXX0jPjMLaztHZwYoXktffyMJUgAPYWIHPDATaPY8ohgkVHRMJKdSACF0UhpgPL5iCUxbewbXNQ8vCHoGdtzO7sS%20lLS%20Fg7yKdxCEnIqOkYWDj1y3MrqtAxgeucARnHJupmmlspe5Jc3Ie96B4bU9O32XfgSaGAUGEUBk7hwphON2aEEsAF5IY8zko-sQAVAAEzA0GkcEIhrQ1r8Wj8Fjw06kJHsIA) for this example.

You can see that there's an error for variable `t`

```
Type 'typeof Module1' is not assignable to type 'typeof ModuleBase'.
  Construct signature return types 'Module1' and 'ModuleBase<P, S>' are incompatible.
    The types of 'state' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'Readonly<IModuleState> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S> | undefined'.
        Type 'Readonly<IModuleState>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<S>'.(2322)
```

which doesn't make much sense to me given that the type parameters are hard coded in `Module1`.

By accident I found the approach used for variable `t2` and I'm surprised this actually works (using TS 4.9.3). This reminds me a bit on Java generics, however I could not find a description for this feature in the [Typescript Generics Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content).

So I wonder, how this feature is officially named (ignored type parameters?) and where I can find documentation for it?

**Update**

Not part of this question, but since this came up from a problem I tried to solve here the correct solution to avoid `any` or the (soon-to-be-removed) `?`:

`const t2: typeof ModuleBase<IModuleProperties, IModuleState> = Module1;`

Comment: What?!!! This has *got* to be a bug in TypeScript.  There is no question mark syntax for type arguments, and I'm sure the compiler will interpret this as `ModuleBase<any, any>`.  Let me see if anyone's reported this, and if not, I will.

Comment: It's even provided by type hints in VS Code (which is how I found it) :-)

Comment: All right, I filed [ms/TS#51802](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51802) and will post an answer here when it gets triaged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such feature in TypeScript.  You've encountered a bug where [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) apparently allow [JSDoc type hints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html#providing-type-hints-in-js-via-jsdoc), but they shouldn't; see [microsoft/TypeScript#51802](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51802). I filed this issue today, and the TS team has already merged [microsoft/TypeScript#51804](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51804) to fix it.  That means it will break starting with the next [nightly build](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/nightly-builds.html), and be released with TypeScript 5.0 at the latest, so you shouldn't keep using it.  Since the `?` is apparently being interpreted as [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) in your example code anyway, you can change `?` to `any` to keep it working the same way.

That's the answer to the question as asked. It's possible that your underlying use case would be better solved with something other than `any`, but that would be out of scope for this question.

Comment: [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51804) is already on its way 

Comment: @TobiasS. Yeah I was just in the middle of editing to say that.  I feel bad for OP because they were like "hey look at this neat feature" and I'm immediately like "no, you're doing it wrong"

Comment: Great that this issue can be solved so quickly. Now I need to find another solution for my problem. And I was so happy for a moment. 